# How to know the exact exception type in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.Net web application where I am performing log in operation. But when I call the log in service I get below exeption.

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]


if (loginType == LoginTypeEnum.Google)
{
    result = AuthenticateByGoogle(username, password);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string x = ex.GetType().ToString(); // What to write here to get the exact exception
    return x;
}
```

Just for debugging purpose I am returning the string x and displaying it in the front end by adding it in the error bag. I think FaultException is a generic exception type. So how can I pin point the exact exception from "ex". I am a beginner so please guide me.

Comment: Why not just let your application throw the exception?

Comment: I am a beginner. Can you please tell me what you want me to do. I will do as you guide me.

Comment: You should really avoid showing users of your application technical things such as exception types. You might be better off showing `ex.Message` but even that is likely too much.

Comment: Actually I am not able to debug inside the `AuthenticateByGoogle` method, so humor me on this. Is there any way I can get the exception in the string variable that I have in my code.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking though.

Comment: Okey, I am getting some exception out of `AuthenticateByGoogle` function. My breakpoint hits at `catch (Exception ex)` . So I have alot of stuff in `ex` variable. So How can I know the exact exception which occurred. Which parameter in `ex` will tell me the exact exception which occurred. Am I making sense?

Comment: The exact exception that occurred is `FaultException`, but you might have something inside `InnerException`. But you might get some better information out of the stack trace. If you're looking for some generic single piece of info to extract from the exception, there isn't one thing. You really need all of it.

Comment: Ok. Suppose the `innerexception` has some clue then how can I put it in my string variable. `string x = ex. // what to write here`

Comment: The point is that every exception has different properties that are important. There is no generic way.

Comment: @DavidG : I see. I get what you are saying. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ex.GetType().Name; will return the exact exception type. Use like this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  string x = ex.GetType().Name;
  return x;
}
```